# How to remove elements from json file using python?

Tags: python, json

I have a json file which looks like this

```
{
   "name1": {
                  "name": "xyz",
                   "roll": "123",
                   "id": "A1"
            },
    "name2":{
                  "name": "abc",
                   "roll": "456",
                   "id": "A2"             
            },
    "name3":{
                  "name": "def",
                   "roll": "789",
                   "id": "B1"             
            }
}
```

I want to remove `name1`, `name2`, `name3` and should be looking like this

```
{
            {
                  "name": "xyz",
                   "roll": "123",
                   "id": "A1"
            },
            {
                  "name": "abc",
                   "roll": "456",
                   "id": "A2"             
            },
            {
                  "name": "def",
                   "roll": "789",
                   "id": "B1"             
            }
}
```

Is there any way to do this in python? If this problem is asked earlier then me please refer to one cause I can't find it. Help will be thankful.

Comment: That wouldn't be valid JSON.

Comment: @Unmitigated is the previous one is valid json or is there any way to make valid one?

Comment: The original file is valid, but the format you want is not.

Comment: You could use `[ ]`  instead of `{ }` If you want to  achieve above format. 

`[ {}, {}, {}]` - So this will be a valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're expecting the outermost (root) level of json document to be an object (curly braces) you should specify at least one key to start with. Refer below example.

Python code Example

```
import json

in_file = open("/Input/path/to/sample.json", "r")

out_file = open("/Output/path/to/converted_json.json", "w")

input_json = json.load(in_file)
print(input_json)

converted_json = {"names": [input_json[key] for key in input_json]}
print(converted_json)

json.dump(converted_json, out_file)

in_file.close(), out_file.close()
```

Out put will be a json file with name `converetd_json.json` with below content.

```
{
"names": [{
        "name": "xyz",
        "roll": "123",
        "id": "A1"
    },
    {
        "name": "abc",
        "roll": "456",
        "id": "A2"
    },
    {
        "name": "def",
        "roll": "789",
        "id": "B1"
    }
   ]
}
```

If you want to avoid this root key, an alternative is to use an `array` (Square Brackets) as an outermost level. Refer below example.

Python Code

```
import json

in_file = open("/Input/path/to/sample.json", "r")

out_file = open("/Output/path/to/converted_json.json", "w")

input_json = json.load(in_file)
print(input_json)

converted_json = [input_json[key] for key in input_json]
print(converted_json)

json.dump(converted_json, out_file)

in_file.close(), out_file.close()
```

Out put will be a json file with name `converetd_json.json` with below content.

```
[
  {
    "name": "xyz",
    "roll": "123",
    "id": "A1"
  },
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "roll": "456",
    "id": "A2"
  },
  {
    "name": "def",
    "roll": "789",
    "id": "B1"
   }
]
```

Note: The outermost level of a JSON document is either an "object" (curly braces) or an "array" (square brackets). So in this case both are valid json.

Comment: `converted_json = [input_json[key...` is a long way of writing `converted_json = list(inout_json.values())`

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple python script. First, you need to read the json file and then load it as an json object. Then, you can iterate on the whole json object to change it to whatever format you need.

```py
import json

with open("file.json","r+") as file:
    s = file.read()
jfile = json.loads(s)


with open("ss.json","w") as file:
    json.dump([jfile[i] for i in jfile], file)
```

Comment: This doesn't do what op wants. Admittedly, that is impossible to do, but you should still mention that in your answer, and explain what your code actually does instead. See [answer]